# Multi File upload "files[]" javascript validation

Tags: javascript, validation

On my site I have multi file upload form with fields:

```
<input name="files[]" type="file" id="files" size="30" />
<input name="files[]" type="file" id="files" size="30" />
<input name="files[]" type="file" id="files" size="30" />
```

and I want to validate this fields with javascript code, I know how to get value for some simple fields with javascript but I don`t know how to get values from this fields with names "files[]", how javascript see this fields, array or...?
How to apply validation of size and file type using javascript

Comment: Not quite get it, but I assume you want to select the DOM? Try change the `id` to `class`, since you cannot have multiple IDs, and use `document.getElementsByClassName("files")` to select the DOM.

Comment: for which type of files you want to put validation?

Comment: Hope it can help somebody https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64663160/jquery-validate-filesize-in-multidimensional-array-dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input name="files[]" type="file" id="files[]" size="30" />
<input name="files[]" type="file" id="files[]" size="30" />
<input name="files[]" type="file" id="files[]" size="30" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Get File Name-Type-Size</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, file;

    if (!window.FileReader) {
        bodyAppend("p", "The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
        return;
    }

    var input=document.getElementsByName('files[]');
 for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++){
     var file = input[i].files[0];
   bodyAppend("p", "File " + file.name + " is " + formatBytes(file.size) + " in size"+" & type is "+ fileType(file.name));    
  }
 }

 //function to append result to view
 function bodyAppend(tagName, innerHTML) {
  var elm;

  elm = document.createElement(tagName);
  elm.innerHTML = innerHTML;
  document.body.appendChild(elm);
 }
 
 //function to find size of file in diff UNIT
 function formatBytes(bytes,decimals) {
    if(bytes == 0) return '0 Byte';
    var k = 1000;
    var dm = decimals + 1 || 3;
    var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];
    var i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));
    return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm)) + ' ' + sizes[i];
 }

 //function to find file type
 function fileType(filename){
  return (/[.]/.exec(filename)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(filename) : undefined;
 }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Check this now you can put conditions on type of file & size.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this jQuery ;)
$("form").on('change', 'input[type=file]', function() {
    var file;
    var this = $(this);
    if (file = this.files[0])
    {
        var img = new Image();

        img.onload = function () {
            // correct 
            // check alert(img.src)
        }

        img.onerror = function () {
            //error info
        };

        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>




<input name="files[]" type="file" id="files[]" size="30" />
<input name="files[]" type="file" id="files[]" size="30" />
<input name="files[]" type="file" id="files[]" size="30" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Get File Type</button>
<script>

function myFunction() {
var file=document.getElementsByName('files[]');
for(var i=0;i<file.length;i++){
console.log(file[i].value);
}

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

you can get files name like this.

Comment: Thanks But how can apply image size validation and type validation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Bhavik vora But already done with this one

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <title>client-side image (type/size) upload validation</title>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <style>
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form><fieldset><legend>Image upload</legend>
    <input type="file"  name="file[]" onchange="getImg(this,100,'jpeg|png')">
    <input type="file"  name="file[]" onchange="getImg(this,100,'jpeg|png')">  
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script>
    function getImg(input,max,accepted){
        var upImg=new Image(),test,size,msg=input.form;
        msg=msg.elements[0].children[0];

        return input.files?validate():
        (upImg.src=input.value,upImg.onerror=upImg.onload=validate);
            "author: b.b. Troy III p.a.e";
        function validate(){
            test=(input.files?input.files[0]:upImg);
            size=(test.size||test.fileSize)/1024;
            mime=(test.type||test.mimeType);
        mime.match(RegExp(accepted,'i'))?
        size>max?(input.form.reset(),msg.innerHTML=max+"KB Exceeded!"):
        msg.innerHTML="Upload ready...":    
        (input.form.reset(),msg.innerHTML=accepted+" file type(s) only!")
        }
    }
    </script> 
    </body>
    </html>
```